# MultiSelect List with Navigation

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to create a sap.m.List that can be used both for multiple selection and to navigate to another view (depending on where on the list item the user taps)?

My scenario is that I am displaying a summary list of events that can either be approved or rejected en masse by the user. Ideally though I'd like the user to be able to tap on one of the list items and be taken to a view that has more info on that list item.

The problem now is that with MultiSelect lists, tapping anywhere on a list item selects that item.

Comment: Hi, check the https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.38.25/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#getIncludeItemInSelection property, maybe it's possible to switch-off the selection of item by the row click.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrii, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the answer here in case someone faces this issue.

You can choose to define the selection of the list item in two different ways:

**1. Select the list item by clicking on the selection control:**

```
    <List 
    id="InvoiceList"
    headerText="{i18n>listHeader}"
    items="{
        path : 'invoice>/Invoices'
        }"
        mode="MultiSelect"
```

> ```
>       includeItemInSelection=false    <---- this is the default of value of the propoerty.
> ```

This should work as:
[image: Item select with only with selection control]

**2. Select the list item clicking anywhere on the list:**

```
    <List 
    id="InvoiceList"
    headerText="{i18n>listHeader}"
    items="{
        path : 'invoice>/Invoices'
        }"
        mode="MultiSelect"
```

> ```
>       includeItemInSelection=true
> ```

This will include the selection of the list item upon clicking anywhere.

As mentioned by Andrii Naumovych, you can find more information about the property [Define item selection with property IncludeItemInSelection](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.38.25/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#getIncludeItemInSelection)